# How is it possible to DATA bind a dictionary<string, list<string>> to a listbox in C#-WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, data-binding

C# Code-

```
namespace WPFDataBinding
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public Person Obj { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Obj = new Person();
            List<string> subjects1 = new List<string>();
            subjects1.Add("C"); subjects1.Add("C++"); subjects1.Add("C#");
            List<string> subjects2 = new List<string>();
            subjects2.Add("JAVA"); subjects2.Add("JS"); subjects2.Add("CSS");
            Obj.studDetail.Add("Kush", subjects1);
            Obj.studDetail.Add("Yash", subjects2);
            DataContext = this;
         }

        public class Person
        {
            private Dictionary<string, List<string>> StudDetail = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            public Dictionary<string, List<string>> studDetail
            {   
                get { return StudDetail; }
                set { StudDetail = value; }
            }
        }
    }
}




WPF code------

<ListBox  FontSize="20" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100" Background="Gray">
    <Label Content="{Binding Obj}">
        <Label.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListBox Height="Auto"  FontSize="20" MinHeight="100"
    MinWidth="100" Width="Auto" Name="Sub1" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding studDetail}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Label.ContentTemplate>
    </Label>
</ListBox>
```

I wrote this code but the result is not what i expected.Do anyone know what to do in this situation? If yes, Plz Help to solve it.

Comment: What do you expect it to display in the ListBox? The Keys from the dictionary, all the strings from all the lists combined in to a single list, or something else?

Comment: @BradleyUffner i want to display the 1 list in a listbox which have a key "Kush".

Comment: @kushagrabisht: How do you want to display the subjects?

Comment: In a listbox like a list one below the other @mm8

Comment: Never mind I worked it out. Thanks for your help. I'm grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `IValueConverter` to change the data in to a usable form.

If you just want all of the strings in the list of strings clumped together in one list, you can use this converter:

```
public class StudentDetailsConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var data = value as Dictionary<string, List<string>>;
        return data.Values.SelectMany(v => v);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You will have to add this as a resource someplace accessible in your XAML; the Window  is one possibility.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:StudentDetailsConverter x:Key="StudentDetailsConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Then change your binding to this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=studDetail, Converter={staticResource StudentDetailsConverter}}"
```

If you want something different, please update your question.